# Getting error create null as blank is deprecated in selenium webdriver

Tags: apache-poi

I am working on excel reading automation in selenium webdriver. There are some blank cell in excel.

Actually I have create an excel file with some data like username and password and have given some column (username) values as blank. And when I have run the code it show the exception NullPointerExceptions. So I have Create the object of MissingCellPolicy class and pass in the object in cellcount as a second argument with J. But its show the warning message on below line code:

MissingCellPolicy MCP = Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK;`
 .
The field Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK is deprecated.

Following code is displayed blank for only First Line columns. For example
Coli1  Column2
Manoj Test
Kumar QA
Test
      Rahul
Vinit Sumit
Umesh Naresh

Its displayed blank only for First column under the Test blank should be displayed  under the QA also.Please help where i have did mistake.

public class ExcelRead {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    File fObj = new File("C:\\Selenium\\WebDriverWorkspace\\APERIOSuite\\src\\testData\\Login.xlsx");

     FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(fObj);

     XSSFWorkbook wb= new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

     XSSFSheet sheetObj= wb.getSheetAt(0);

     int rcount = sheetObj.getLastRowNum();

     MissingCellPolicy MCP=Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK;

     for(int i=0;i<=rcount;i++){

         Row rowObj=sheetObj.getRow(i);

         int cellcnt=rowObj.getLastCellNum();

         for(int j=0; j<=cellcnt-1;j++){

            Cell cellObj=rowObj.getCell(j,MCP);

            String cellvalue =cellObj.getStringCellValue();

            System.out.println(cellvalue);
```

Comment: Your question doesn't contain a question. What are you needing help with?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Your question doesn't sound like it has anything to do with Selenium. it sounds like it's an issue you are having with the Excel related library that you are using. Please fix the tags on the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the POI library 3.15 from Apache. The new way looks like this:

```java
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
wb.setMissingCellPolicy(MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
```

Edited to fit in your example.

Comment: Yes right, can you please guide me to how to write code for this and where should change in the code